# How do I put text next to bordered text?

Tags: html, css

```
<img src="nature.jpg" alt="Naturez" style="width:1350px; height:170px">
<p class="border">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">Home Page</a>
```

whenever I place any text after "Home Page" the text always goes below. How do I put the text next to "Home Page" ?

Comment: Show please how do you type the text,(after "Home Page").

Comment: This would be a css issue - can you share your styles?

Comment: We need to see the CSS for the `.border` class. Better yet, a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Show HTML and CSS that actually reproduce the issue and say what you mean by “goes below”.

Comment: What you are looking for is the 'inline' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @AlexW said, need a closing `</p>`. But also note that this can be handled in CSS.

```
<p class="border" style="display: inline-block;"><a href...>Home Page</a></p> Text text text.
```

But I would recommend using the `<p>` tag only to represent a block displayed paragraph, and use a styled `<span>` tag to add a border to an inline element:

```
<p><span class="border"><a href="...">Home Page</a></span> Text text text.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a typo, but you are missing a closing `</p>` tag.

You need to put the text *inside* of the `<p class="border"></p>` to have it show up next to the `<a>` element because `<p>` is a block-level element and will not let anything appear beside it. The text may also be wrapping to the next line because the area is too small for it to fit properly.

Comment: I think he is putting it inside.

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect the markup to see WHY it is being pushed down. Is the 'border' class setting a width that is too narrow? You could increase this property. You could also set a width on the anchor element to ensure it was wide enough.